# Which one is faster? MATLAB SVM or scikit SVM?

Tags: svm, matlab, scikit-learn

Which one is faster, SVM from MATLAB or SVM from scikitlearn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by SVM from MATLAB. The implementation in the bioinformatics toolbox sucks. If you use LIBSVM bindings in MATLAB, then the speed will be exactly the same as sklearn's SVM, since they are identical.